# Reference request for simple $q-$ identities

Tags: reference-request, q-identities

I stumbled upon the following  simple $q-$identities:
$$\frac{1}{(-q;q)_\infty}\sum \limits_{j =0}^{\infty}\frac{q^{(2r+1)j}}{(q^2;q^2)_j}=(q;q^2)_r$$
and
$$\frac{1}{(q;q^2)_\infty}\sum \limits_{j =0}^{\infty}(-1)^{j}\frac{q^{(r+1)j}}{(q;q)_j}=(-q;q)_r,$$
where $r\in\mathbb{N} $ and $\binom{r}{j}_q$ denotes a $q-$binomial coefficient.

Probably these are well known. But where can I find such identities?  Are there tables of $q-$identities in the literature?

Answer (score 5):

You can use eqn. (1), (2) and (5) in [this file](https://carma.newcastle.edu.au/wadim/PS/mpim-mar2006.pdf) to show the identities.

Comment: Thanks for the advertisement! Yes, indeed, all those identities are particular cases of the $q$-binomial theorem...

Comment: @Satoshi: Thank you. I used essentially the same methods to prove these identities. But I want to know if the identities in the given form appear in the literature and moreover if somewhere are tables of known $q-$identities where possibly analogous formulae can be found.

Comment: These are simplest variants of Rogers-Ramanujan (Andrews-Gordon) identities and they are also called quantum dilogarithm identities. You can google these words to reach the original references.